# Optimal path to see every square on a grid

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I have a game where a `Player` object is moving around a grid, attempting to explore as much of the space as possible. Each move, the `Player` can see the square it is on as well as the 8 adjacent squares. What is the optimal path that a player could take in order to see all squares at least once in the fewest moves (with diagonal motion allowed)?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no obstacles, the shortest path would be simply going up to the second row of the grid, across three squares and then back down to the second to bottom.

Comment: Sorry, just made an edit. Diagonal moves are allowed, so I'm mostly wondering how a path that consists of mostly diagonal moves should behave at the edges of the grid.